# How can python script call API define in robotremoteserver library?

Tags: robotframework, remote-server, xmlrpclib

my robotremoteserver library defines some API like startenv, stopenv

```
from robotremoteserver import RobotRemoteServer

class myLibrary(object):
    def startenv(self):
        return "start"
    def stopenv(self):
        return "stop"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RobotRemoteServer(myLibrary(), *sys.argv[1:])
```

I tried a c.txt as robot file and was able to call API,

```
** Settings ***
Library       Remote    http://serverxxxx:8720
*** Test Cases ***
startenv
    ${rc} =    startenv
stopenv
    ${rc} =    stopenv
```

but How can we call these from remote XMLRPC python client script?
tried things as below

```
from robot.libraries.Remote import Remote
s = Remote('http://serverxxxx:8270')
s.startenv()
s.run_keyword("startenv")
```

But none works :(

Answer (score 0):

It should be
s.run_keyword("startenv",None,None).
run_keyword() takes 4 positional arguments